# How to define a function that receives a pointer as argument and returns a pointer to one of the argument's children?

Tags: pointers, go

I'm having my first contact with pointers now that I'm learning Go.

But this is getting a little tricky and I'm starting to question whether I'm doing it right or wrong.

The title is my best guess to try and explain what I'm trying to do in a foreign language, so if it's unclear, I can try to explain in a different way.

This is a simplified example of the code: https://play.golang.org/p/eultYp7Cq12

```
func hasCity(element string, state *State) (bool, *City) {
    for _, city := range (*state).Cities {
        if (city.Name == element) {
            return true, &city
        }
    }
    return false, nil
}
```

As you can see, the output is:

```
true &{Campinas}
[{SP [{São Paulo} {Barueri}]}]
```

But what I'm actually trying to get is:

```
true &{Campinas}
[{SP [{São Paulo} {Campinas}]}]
```

So, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: There are no diffrence between the output and expected result. Now what you want to do?

Comment: When posting a question, please include the relevant code *in the body of the question* rather than at an external link.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Adrian, will definitely do that in the next questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function returns the address of the local variable `cities`.  Change the code to return the address of the slice element:

```
func hasCity(element string, state *State) (bool, *City) {
    for i, city := range state.Cities {
        if city.Name == element {
            return true, &state.Cities[i]
        }
    }

    return false, nil
}
```

Comment: It not only worked perfectly but also helped me understand what happened. Thanks!

Comment: @klferreira it's worth noting that a more idiomatic approach in golang would be to return the pointer as first return value, and an error value if the city wasn't found. Same goes for the arguments: I'd pass the `State` value in first (ie `func hasCity(state *State, city string) (*City, error) {}`